# Android wrong activity being launched

Tags: android

I am trying to navigate to StockMarketNewsActivity, when newsButton is clicked, but it takes me to the wrong activity. I am not sure why, could someone assist me? I have been stuck on this bug for quite some time..I have already tried cleaning my project as well as invalidate/restarting my ide, but nothing seems to fix this problem..

```
public class NewsFeedFragment extends Fragment {
        private RecyclerView newsFeedRecycleView;
        private NewsFeedAdapter newsFeedAdapter;
    
    
        private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
        private String usersPostId;
        private String userPostTimeStamp;
        private TextView deleteTextView, greetingsTv, niceDatTv, bokNeedTv, moreBookOption;
    
        private EditText seachEditText;
        private String selectedUserName, selectedUserProfilePic, id, time;
    
        private ImageView searchStockImageView;
        private ImageView uploadImage, hamburgerItem, loggedInUserPic;
        private View rootView;
        private Toolbar mToolBar;
        private JSONObject stockDetails;
    
        private Button newsButton, stockAnalysisButton;
    
    
        private ArrayList<TopMentionedStocksModel> stockInfosArrayList;
    
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsfeed_fragment_layout, container, false);
    
            stockInfosArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    
            searchStockImageView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchStockImageView);
    
            newsButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.newsButton);
            stockAnalysisButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.stockAnalysis);
    
    
            searchStockImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Tapped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    
    
            //this hides keyboard
            getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
    
    
            initRecycleView();
    
    
            //navigate to search stock activity when clicked..
            searchStockImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), StockMarketNewsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    

**I am trying to navigate to news activity when newsButton is clicked.**
            newsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    
    
                    Log.i("NewsButtonTappeD", "news button tapped");
    
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), StockMarketNewsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
    
                }
            });
    
    
            stockAnalysisButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Analyze_Stocks_Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
    
                }
            });
    
    
            return rootView;
    
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
    
            //ownloadJson(Constants.MOST_ACTIVE_STOCK_API);
    
            downloadTopMentionedStocks(Constants.TOP_MENTIONED_STOCKS_API);
    
    
        }
    
    
        //set up RecycleVIew/listener to detect taps layout manager tels recycle view how to display the list.. without it, nothing shows up
        public void initRecycleView() {
            newsFeedRecycleView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.stockInfoRecycleView);
            // layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
            //layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    
    
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            newsFeedRecycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    
    
            newsFeedAdapter = new NewsFeedAdapter(getActivity(), stockInfosArrayList);
            newsFeedRecycleView.setAdapter(newsFeedAdapter);
        }
    
    
        public void downloadTopMentionedStocks(String ur) {
    
    
            //making the progressbar visible
            //creating a string request to send request to the url
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ur,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            //hiding the progressbar after completion
    
    
                            try {
    
                                JSONObject stockObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONObject getObject = stockObject.getJSONObject("data");
                                JSONArray getArray = getObject.getJSONArray("all");
    
    
                                //now looping through all the elements of the json array
                                for (int i = 0; i < getArray.length(); i++) {
                                    //getting the json object of the particular index inside the array
    
                                    JSONObject stockData = getArray.getJSONObject(i);
    
                                    Log.i("tickeer", stockData.getString("ticker"));
    
    
                                    TopMentionedStocksModel topMentionedStocksModel = new TopMentionedStocksModel(stockData.getString("total_mentions"), stockData.getString("positive_mentions"), stockData.getString("negative_mentions"), stockData.getString("neutral_mentions"), stockData.getString("ticker"), stockData.getString("name"), stockData.getString("sentiment_score"));
    
    
                                    stockInfosArrayList.add(topMentionedStocksModel);
    
                                    //Log.i("stockArray", stockInfosArrayList.toString());
                                    newsFeedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    
    
                                    //Log.i("stockData", stockData.toString());
    
    
                                }
    
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                            // Toast.makeTextt(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
    
            //creating a request queue
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    
            //adding the string request to request queue
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    
        }
```

Comment: which activity is opening?

Comment: Analyize_Stock_Activity... I have already tested the buttons. The right one is being tapped on..

Comment: yah that whats i guess

Comment: please check ` stockAnalysisButton` is tegering at bthe same time i think

Comment: Check your ``StockMarketNewsActivity.java`` file then, you might have implemented redirection to another activity or you might have mistakenly named the wrong class file name with ``StockMarketNewsActivity``

Comment: do you get this in the log "news button tapped"?
Assuming that your fragment NewsFeedFragment is not being loaded into StockMarketNewsActivity, and the _launchmode is standard_ for the current loaded activity and StockMarketNewsActivity, I think you should try File->invalidate and restart

Answer (score 2):

As [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) said:

> It is recommended to **only** inflate the layout in this method and move logic that operates on the returned View to onViewCreated(View, Bundle).

So try to move all `setOnClickListener` to `onViewCreated`.